# TypeScript compiler complains require() file outside of rootDir when import() is also used

Tags: typescript, commonjs, es6-modules

In a project setup like [this](https://glitch.com/~aromatic-bittersweet-biplane), tsc complains requiring a file outside of `rootDir`.

```
yarn tsc
yarn run v1.15.2
$ /app/node_modules/.bin/tsc
src/index.ts:2:36 - error TS6059: File '/app/package.json' is not under 'rootDir' '/app/src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.

2 const {version: VERSION} = require('../package.json');
```

But if there is no `await import()` in `index.ts`, tsc will just compile the whole thing:

```
async function foo() {
    let obj = {}; //await import('./anotherFile');
    console.log(obj);
}
```

```
$ yarn tsc
yarn run v1.15.2
$ /app/node_modules/.bin/tsc
Done in 3.83s.
```

Why do tsc only complaint when `require()` and `import()` coexist?

Comment: Resolved by TypeScript team [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38611)